# How is the number of distinct right cosets of a cyclic subgroup generated by an element equal to the order of the element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading *Group Theory* from *Topics in Algebra* by *I.N.Herstein* where he discussed about some corollaries of the Lagrange's Theorem; the concerned one is:

> If $G$ is a finite group, and $a\in G,$ then $a^{o(G)}= e\,.$

Here $o(~)$ means the *order of $~$*.

[image]

In the proof, he wrote:

> [...] $o(a)~| ~o(G);$ thus $o(G)= \mathrm m~o(a)$ ...

In the preceding para, he defined $\mathrm m$ as the least positive integer such that $a^\mathrm m = e\,.$

How did the author write $o(G) = \mathrm m~ o(a)\,?$

In two pages earlier, he defined $\frac{o(G)}{o(H)}$ for a subgroup $H$ as equal to the number of distinct right cosets of $H$ in $G\,.$

So, does that mean $\frac{o(G)}{o(a)}= \mathrm m$ is the number of distinct right cosets of cyclic subgroup $(a)\,?$

How did the author conclude that?

How is the order of $a$ equal to the number of distinct right cosets of the subgroup $(a)\,?$

Comment: We have that $o(a)$ is the order of the cyclic subgroup $(a)$, i.e., $o(a)=|(a)|$ and Lagrange's theorem says that $o(G)=o(H)[G:H]$, where $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Yes, I very much do agree with that.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Perhaps showing us the entire proof would help?

Comment: @TroyG, done; I think the $m$ in the proof is different from the $m$ in the definition.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Yes, poor choice of notation by the author is all that is. :) It turns out the only requirement for $m$ is that it is an integer, not necessarily the order of $a$.

Comment: okay, gotcha @TroyG; thanks.